# How to pass a variable from the controller into the extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a variable (SelectedProfiles) that returns a list of profiles that are selected from a multi-select picklist on a VF page, and is used in the where clause in a SOQL query that returns the CRUD permissions by profile for the objects. How do I pass the variable  values  from the controller (GetFLSController) to the extension to use in the query?

Here is the extension.

```
public class OLSExtension {

public OLSExtension(GetFLSController obj){}

List<ObjectPermissions> ObjectPerms = [SELECT Id, ParentId, SobjectType, 
PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsRead, 
PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, 
PermissionsCreate 
     FROM ObjectPermissions
     Where (ParentId IN :GetFLSController.SelectedProfiles)];
        public List<ObjectPermissions> getObjPerms(){
        return ObjectPerms;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused here. Normally you either have a custom controller or a standard controller and one or more controller extensions, but you seem to be saying you have both a custom controller and controller extensions. Is that what you mean? What does the custom controller look like, and can you also include the actual apex:page tag from your Visualforce page file so we can see how you are using both?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Phil W here as Extension classes apply to StandardControllers and it looks like you are using `OLSExtension` as a Helper class, not an extension

Hence, if this is correct, then you would code as follows

```
public class OLSHelper {
  GetFLSController flsController;
  public OLSHelper(GetFLSController flsController){
     this.flsController = flsController;
  }

   List<ObjectPermissions> ObjectPerms = [SELECT Id, ParentId, SobjectType, 
         PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsRead, 
         PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, 
         PermissionsCreate 
     FROM ObjectPermissions
     Where (ParentId IN :flsController.SelectedProfiles)];

  public List<ObjectPermissions> getObjPerms(){
        return ObjectPerms;
    }
}
```

and you would invoke it from class GetFLSController as follows

```
ObjectPermission[] objperms = new OLSHelper(this).getObjPerms();
```

> Having said all this, I would almost never pass an instance of a
>   controller as an object to a helper class; the helper class should
>   accept the list of profiles as the argument as it doesn't really care about how the profiles are collected. See Separation of Concerns principle).

That is, this is better:

```
ObjectPermission[] objperms = new OLSHelper().getObjPerms(profileList);
```

in which case the code looks like:

```
public class OLSHelper {
  public OLSHelper(){}


   List<ObjectPermissions> ObjectPerms = [SELECT Id, ParentId, SobjectType, 
         PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsRead, 
         PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, 
         PermissionsCreate 
     FROM ObjectPermissions
     Where (ParentId IN :flsController.SelectedProfiles)];

  public List<ObjectPermissions> getObjPerms(){
        return ObjectPerms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was trying to add the option to list out the objects and permissions by profile to an existing VF page that we have. I didn't want to add it to the current custom controller to minimize the potential of causing problems with it. That said, I'm new to apex development so any suggestions are welcome.

I added the second suggestion, but am getting an error "Constructor not defined: [OLSHelper].<Constructor>()"

Comment: @DGOU182 - amended answer